# Is it possible to load doctrine fixtures without deleting database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I have defined some `fixtures` in `doctrine`.

When i try to run using this

`php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load` then it asks me to purge the database.

is it possible to load it without purging database.

I remeber `Django` has `fixtures` which can be loaded in separate tables without purging existing database

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the `--append` option

```
php app/console help doctrine:fixtures:load
Usage:
 doctrine:fixtures:load [--fixtures[="..."]] [--append] [--em="..."] [--purge-with-truncate]

Options:
 --fixtures             The directory or file to load data fixtures from. (multiple values allowed)
 --append               Append the data fixtures instead of deleting all data from the database first.
 --em                   The entity manager to use for this command.
 --purge-with-truncate  Purge data by using a database-level TRUNCATE statement
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Unfortunately, this adds entries again, which have already been added. Hence, it leads to duplicates. Any possibility to avoid that?

Comment: @Simon Yes, don't load them again. Put your new fixtures in a separate folder (date-stamps make good names) and use the `--fixtures` option.

Comment: No other possibility? Pity. Then I have to know myself which fixtures I already loaded and which fixtures I still have to load. Not really a feasible solution...

Comment: I created an issue for the problem in the [DoctrineFixturesBundle GitHub repository](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues/121).

Comment: @Phil How can we exclude some tables (for example, country, city, etc) to be purged via `doctrine:fixtures:load`? Is there any yaml configuration file or sth else?

Comment: @YahyaE I suggest you open a new question

Comment: --append could lead you to duplicated items

Comment: @famas23 yes, that was already discussed above

Answer (score 3):

DoctrineFixtures are nice for the first init of an empty database or in development - but not in production.

Take a look at [DoctrineMigrations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/index.html) and symfonys [DcotrineMigrationsBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html), this is a good and safe way to migrate your database in production.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to update previously added data to DB (which was loaded by running *app/console doctrine:fixtures:load*). I used EntityManager->createQuery for that.

But I still wonder if there is or ever will be an opportunity to do it by simply running an app/console command. Something like *app/console doctrine:schema:update --force*, but applied to the data itself.

For now I had to write a ton of code to get my data updated and appended properly. For example to make *--append* work I had to write the following:

```
    class LoadCategoryData implements FixtureInterface
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public function load(ObjectManager $em)
        {
            //a category has name and shortcut name (st)
            $categories = array (
                [0]=> array('name' => 'foo', 'st' = 'bar'),
                ...
            );

            foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                $query = $em->createQuery(
                    "SELECT c
                    FROM MyBundle:Category c
                    WHERE c.st = ?1"
                )->setParameter(1, $cat['st'])->getResult();

                if (count($query) == 0) {
                    $c = new Category();
                    $c->setName($cat['name']);
                    $c->setSt($cat['st']);

                    $em->persist($c);
                }

                $em->flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: One more question. What would be the best way to pass data to the FixtureInterface implementation? I consider declaring it as an array (like I sh*tcoded above) is not the most efficient way ever.. Thnx.